# Why can a multiline comment appear between "import" and ImportSpec, but not between PackageName and ImportPath?

Tags: go, language-lawyer, specifications

This is the Go spec for an import declaration:

```
ImportDecl       = "import" ( ImportSpec | "(" { ImportSpec ";" } ")" ) .
ImportSpec       = [ "." | PackageName ] ImportPath .
ImportPath       = string_lit .
```

The following code compiles:

```
import /*
 */f "fmt"
```

But not this code:

```
import /*
 */f/*
 */"fmt"
```

Even more strangely, this code compiles:

```
import /*
 */f /* */ "fmt"
```

I could not understand the difference between these comment blocks among the tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec)
>
> [Comments](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comments)
>
> General comments start with the character sequence /* and stop with
> the first subsequent character sequence */.
>
> A general comment containing no newlines acts like a space. Any other
> comment acts like a newline.

```
package main

import /*
 */f/*
 */"fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println()
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/nxvIDWkWf_q

```
prog.go:4:5: expected 'STRING', found newline
```